# Is possible to send OTP only with ReactJS(only with plain JS, without NodeJS)

Tags: reactjs, twilio

Is there any way to send OTP only using React(with Vonage or Twilio)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are looking to send an OTP via SMS using a service like Twilio then you will need a back-end of some sort. That back-end does not have to be written in Node.js, you just need a server-side component.

The reason for this is that Twilio, and other APIs, give you a secret, in Twilio's case it is called an Auth Token, that authenticates you with the API and lets your account send those messages. If you try to make calls to the API directly from within your React application, you would expose that Auth Token and a malicious user could take it and use it to abuse your account.

I wrote a post on how to [send SMS messages using React, Twilio and Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-an-sms-react-twilio) that might help you.

If you are trying to send OTP codes, you might find that the [Twilio Verify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify) is actually better suited for this. It is a dedicated API for sending and verifying OTP codes. This blog post shows you how to [build your own Verify service using Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/blog/serverless-phone-verification). The benefit of Twilio Functions is that you don't need to run your own servers, you can host the functions in Twilio's infrastructure.

Let me know if this helps at all.